# How many four digit numbers divisible by five whose digits add up to 6 exist?

Tags: combinatorics

I am just learning the basics of combinatorics and my quick answer to this was 22. Though the approach was a bit rough and I sont know how mathematical in nature.

Comment: That was my logic. If it ends in 6, theres 1 answer. If it ends in 0 I went running through the combinations of an a1a2a35 number where I ran a1 from 1 to 6 and added up all the possible combinations. Did I answer my own question?

Comment: Well, that is how I would solve it. I don't think there is some elegant solution.

Comment: The $22$ is right, obtainable quite quickly by well-organized counting. One can use a little Stars and Bars, it speeds things up a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's divisible by 5, the last digit is either 0 or 5.

For 5, this leaves only one option: 1,005.

For 0, it's a little more complicated.  The first digit has to be at least 1, so you've got 5 more points to spread across three digits; this is a simple partitions problem, of indistinct marbles in distinct urns, and so via stars & bars we get $\binom{7}{2}=21$ possibilities for that.  22 is the answer.

Comment: The strategy to solve partitions problems is also called stars and bars.

Answer (score 0):

The units digit has to be $0$ or $5$, but since the digits have to add up to $6$, the only possibility with $5$ as the units digit is $1005$. Then, with $0$ as the units digit, you can run through the 3 - number partitions of six, including $0$, then go back and exclude the ones that start with $0$.